# How to grab individual elements from an array in store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to implement an app in what I think to be pure `redux` way. Pulling the data out of store and not passing through props.

In the below example, I don't have to pass props to `List` component. It pulls the `list` from store using `connect`. But I don't see any way of pulling `element` from the `list` in store into `Element` component without using props. Is there a way to do this without plumbing it through props?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux'

//Just return the same state
const testReducer = (state=null,{list}) => ({ ...state, list })

function testAction() {
    return {
        type: 'TEST',
        list: ['first','second']
    }
}


const store = createStore(testReducer, [thunk])

store.dispatch(testAction())

class List extends Component {

    render(){
        const {list} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                {list.map((element) => {
                    return(<Element key={element} element={element} />)
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({list}){
    return( {
        list
    })
}

const ConnectList = connect(mapStateToProps)(List)

class Element extends Component {
    render(){
        const {element} = this.props
        return(
            <div>{element}</div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}> 
                    <ConnectList />
                </Provider>, 
                document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Why do you think this is not a proper way of using Redux? You can't get everything from store. Here, you are nicely getting the your `list` from store and passing its elements to a specific component. This is not wrong.

Comment: I see your point. I can't even think there can be another way. But I've been wrong so many times before. So I wanted to confirm

Comment: Yes maybe there might be other ways but this is a very proper and common method. You see this method as an example in a lot of apps in the wild. I've given an answer with an example from Redux documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a proper and common way of passing props to a component with using Redux. Here, your main idea is holding `list` data in your store. You can't hold every item in this data in the store, so only getting the `list` and mapping its items into a separate component via prop is a good way.

Even, in the documentation of Redux they use this in [Todo app example](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/components/TodoList.js).

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, toggleTodo }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

Here TodoList is connected via another component to the store. So it is getting `todos` from store and mapping `Todo` component with `todo` prop.